# Find if a dataset of words contains any words containing all vowels by using exactly 5 calls to str_detect

Tags: strings, functional-programming, regex, r

Take the `words` dataset from `stringr`. [An R4DS exercise](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/strings.html#exercises-38) challenges the reader to check if there are any words in that dataset that contain every vowel. My presumably correct solution, using five calls to `str_detect`, was as follows:

```
library(stringr)
words[apply(sapply(c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u"), function(x) str_detect(words, x)), 1, all)]
```

Under the restriction that we must call `str_detect` exactly five times, once for each vowel, is there a better way to do this? The `sapply` seems like the right idea - it produces a 980*5 logical matrix with each row being a logical vector showing if the corresponding vowel was in the corresponding word. Collapsing it with `all` also seems like the right idea, but any time that I have to call `apply` rather than any other member of the apply family or something like `Filter`, I become concerned about my approach. R's higher-order functions typically work best by column rather than by row and `apply` is a sign that I've failed to work like that.

Suggestions from either base R or the Tidyverse will be accepted. My primary reason for asking this question is that I have a strong feeling that the `apply` could have been avoided, perhaps by construction the logical matrix differently.

Comment: Hello, you wrote that the code you presented is a presumably correct solution for your problem, have you tested it ?

Comment: @dariosicily Yes. It gives the output that I expect. However, one can never be certain when working with this many data points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Sample data**

```r
vowels <- c("a", "e", "i", "o", "u")
input <- c("aeiou", "uoiea", "aeiouc", "aeioo", "coeiauc1", "eu")
```

---

**Solution 1. Use `reduce` and `&`**

These create 5 vectors, but only have 2 loaded at a time.

```r
# 1A: with str_detect
input[Reduce(function(x, y) x & str_detect(input, y), vowels, init = TRUE)]

# 1B: with grepl
input[Reduce(function(x, y) x & grepl(y, input), vowels, init = TRUE)]
```

**Solution 2. Use positive lookaheads**

You can find a complete explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/XgRgxz/1). We are essentially checking for the presence of all the vowels.

```r
# 2A: with str_detect
input[str_detect(input, "(?=.*?a)(?=.*?e)(?=.*?i)(?=.*?o)(?=.*?u)")]

# 2B: with grep
grep("(?=.*?a)(?=.*?e)(?=.*?i)(?=.*?o)(?=.*?u)", input, perl = TRUE, value = TRUE)
```

**Solution 3. Use `strsplit` and `match`**

We can split all the words into individual characters, and then compare `vowels` to the letters of each word. All letters that aren't matched become `0`. Since `0` converts to `FALSE` as a logical, we can use `all` to see if all vowels are present.

```r
input[sapply(strsplit(input, ""), function(x) all(match(vowels, x, nomatch = 0L)))]
```

**Solution 4. `lapply` and `grep`**

We can also choose to generate a vector for each vowel, but just a short one, as `grep` will only return the indices for which the conditions apply. We then use `Reduce` and `intersect` to get our answer. Alternatively, we can use skip `lapply` (solution 4B), but this is slower.

```r
# 4A: with lapply
Reduce(intersect, lapply(vowels, grep, input, value = TRUE))

# 4B: without lapply
Reduce(function(x, y) intersect(x, grep(y, input, value = TRUE)), vowels, init = input)
```

---

**Benchmark of all solutions**

```r
Unit: microseconds
               expr    min      lq      mean median      uq     max neval    cld
    original(words) 1766.7 1936.75 2238.6696 2082.7 2237.00 60182.5 10000      f
 solution_1a(words)  706.7  746.10  839.5126  802.6  868.70  4362.7 10000   c   
 solution_1b(words)  492.5  515.40  586.4063  555.5  605.15 30031.6 10000 a     
 solution_2a(words)  779.4  817.20  906.0936  875.8  940.55 29357.0 10000    d  
 solution_2b(words)  707.4  737.70  819.2046  790.7  854.10  3072.7 10000   c   
  solution_3(words) 1226.4 1376.55 1667.8316 1470.9 1600.95 76907.0 10000     e 
 solution_4a(words)  592.2  641.00  736.0374  689.4  755.20 29589.7 10000  b    
 solution_4b(words)  649.5  704.20  805.9942  757.8  828.80 31104.2 10000   c
```

Memory allocation with `bench::mark`:

```r
                Code    Memory allocation (KB)
1    original(words)                    100.15
2 solution_1a(words)                     42.63
3 solution_1b(words)                     42.63
4 solution_2a(words)                      7.76
5 solution_2b(words)                      3.88
6  solution_3(words)                     38.96
7 solution_4a(words)                     75.67
8 solution_4b(words)                    106.70
```

Comment: I suspect that in many places, `grepl` would serve you better than `grep`.

Comment: A quick benchmark shows that `input[grepl(...)]` is slightly slower than `grep(..., values = TRUE)`, although only by a fraction. Either way, it doesn't lead to any gains.

Comment: Are you sure that we cannot `Reduce`+`intersect` the logical vectors? If the corresponding word contains all five vowels, then all five of the logical vector entries should be `TRUE`. In order to avoid the five `FALSE`s case, we could intersect with a literal `TRUE` via `Reduce`'s `init` argument.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks :) I revamped the whole post. It now contains 4 solutions (some with sub-solutions). I also benchmarked on `words` now instead of on `input`. I also added a memory allocation benchmark, just out of curiosity.